# Increasing column from VARCHAR(255) in master/slave setup

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.1, alter-table

We have replication set up on some MyISAM servers, in a master/save scenario, MySQL v5.1.

One of the columns is currently declared as `VARCHAR(255)`. We want to increase this to `VARCHAR(512)`.

We have one master and 4 slaves. What is the best scenario to make the change.

If we do this:

```
ALTER TABLE item MODIFY url VARCHAR(512)
```

should that be ok, as long as we update the slaves first and then the master, or may it complain and it's best to do them all at once? Should I stop the slaves?

I've tried the update on a dev machine which takes about 10 mins, but it doesn't have replication set there. So looking for any flaws in my thinking.

Or looking further, does `ALTER TABLE` get replicated, and that's all I would need to do on the master?

Comment: *does ALTER TABLE get replicated, and that's all I would need to do on the master?*  Correct.  It replicates automatically unless you specifically prevent  it from doing so, which is sometimes appropriate for long-running operations if you need to do the replicas first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a **replication environment**, for an ALTER that takes a long time, I recommend this:

1. On one slave:  Take out of rotation (keep clients from using it); perform the `ALTER; put back into rotation.
2. Repeat for other slaves.
3. `SET @@session.sql_bin_log = 0` so it won't replicate; do the ALTER; set that back to 1.

That way, Slave users will not be impacted; Master user *may* be impacted.

With **Galera / PXC**, you would use "RSU" (Rolling Slave Update) and have zero downtime (but have to do it manually in a similar manner).

You need to **upgrade to 5.6**.  With it *many* `ALTERs` (probably including your case) can use the fast `ALGORITHM=INPLACE`.